# How do i add a main menu before accessing a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have built an application that revolves around UITableView, Core Data and XML. Now that the app is almost complete i want to add a main menu before accessing the tableView. The main menu will then allow you to navigate to the table and other functions. What is the easiest way to go about doing this? I'm confused about how to change the inital file that is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion would be to add a navigation controller and a new view which will serve as your 'main' view and show your menu. Then in response to the 'menu' choices you could push your existing table view or other views that you might want to show.

Comment: Ok, iv managed to use the navigation controller to load the main menu first but im having trouble now trying to push the existing table view when a button is pressed. Im not sure how to pass the entity's to create the table?

Comment: +entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name '(null)''